# Django Categories with Subcategories, and urls

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

im trying to make Categories and Subcategories, im checking [this models](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookCategoryDataModelPostMagic)
but i have this error:

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'nacionales'
```

where the "nacionales" is the parent Category, i know that my problem maybe are in the urls.py, but the true, i dont know how set the urls for this case...

my model.py:

```
# from ...
class Categoria(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=75, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='child')

# functions....
```

my views.py:

```
# from ... 

def noticias_categoria(request,parent_id,child):
    categoria = get_object_or_404(Categoria,parent=parent_id,slug=child)    
    return object_list(request, queryset=categoria.noticia_set.all(), paginate_by=20,
                       template_name='categorias/categoria_list.html', 
                       extra_context={'categoria':categoria})
```

my Category urls.py:

```
# from ...
url(r'^(?P<parent_id>[-\w]+)/(?P<child>[-\w]+)/$',
                            noticias_categoria,
                            name='noticia_detail'
                            ),
```

my url.py:

```
(r'^categorias/', include('categorias.urls')),
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Can you provide the request (URL) that generated this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're passing in the string value of the parent category - nacionales - where the function is expecting the numeric ID.

Either use an ID for `parent_id`, or rename it to `parent` and write the first line of the function like this:

```
categoria = get_object_or_404(Categoria, parent__titulo=parent, slug=child)
```